# How to prevent static library from getting duplicated?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries

I have a 3rd party static library L (pjsip.lib). This static library depends on many static variables and functions.

I created a DLL D using L. 
I created an application A that uses both D and L.

Here I have a problem. It looks like there multiple instances of static functions and variables that L uses, and they have different values depending on whether it is accessed by  directly A or through L. I am not able to build L as DLL. Is there any way that both A and D can use the same code segment?

I am using Visual C++ (2015).

Answer (score 0):

Place the static lib in its own dll and export all the symbols you need (use a DEF) file it necessary. Now both your exe and other dll can link to it dynamically.